# How to return a blank or dash when one of the cells is left blank?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am looking to calculate pricing and tax between 3 cells. Though if 1 of the cells is blank, I want the end result cell to be blank.

In this instance I have the: **(order total * the tax rate) + the shipping quote**.
But if there is no shipping quote, it is still populating with the first part.

I would like to set it so if there is not shipping quote, it stays blank, or even has a dash there instead.

**This is the formula right now: =(F4*0.25)+G4**

Answer (score 1):

> =iferror(if(G4="","-",(F4*0.25)+G4),"invalid shipping quote")

Dash when no quote, and message when quote has a value but is not a number (just in case there is an incorrect entry)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inclose your formula within the [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en-GB) function:

```
=IF(G4<>"", (F4*0.25)+G4,"-")
```

*(Of course you can change the dash to something more meaningful, like **No shipping quote**)*

As suggesteded at the [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136501/how-to-return-a-blank-or-dash-when-one-of-the-cells-is-left-blank/136507?noredirect=1#comment125087_136507) the formula could also use [`ISBLANK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en-GB)

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G4)), (F4*0.25)+G4,"NO shipping quote")
```

Comment: IMHO it's better to use `ISBLANK(reference)`  to test if a cell is blank because and empty string is not the same that an empty cell.

Comment: @Rubén Correct. Could be used as well. I updated the answer.

Comment: I found cases where ISBLANK() would return false when the value is "", but never found a case where A1=""  returned false when empty.Didn't reaserch, just used the one that worked and moved on

Comment: @ManuelRamirez Thanks for the heads up. Please remember that by [upvoting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) an answer others benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider to use the IF function.
2. To return a blank, leave the IF corresponding parameter blank, i.e.:

   ```
   =IF(ISBLANK(G4),,F4*0.25+G4)
   ```